# python import module in geany or thonny doesn't work, while it does on terminal

Tags: python, geany, realsense, thonny

I'm pretty new to the python thing and have a hard time setting up my environment for development of a intel realsense application on a raspberry pi 4. Coming from Windows PC where everything works nice with pip and all I keep falling over hurdles. On arm there are no ready-to-use packages, so i compiled the python wrappers for librealsense aka pyrealsense2 and exported the directory, where the .so files are placed into my .bashrc as recommended:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib:$PYTHONPATH
```

Then I have tried to import the wrappers in python2 and 3, which works fine on terminal in python 3, but not in python2. Because I want to use python3 anyways, that's fine for me.
I'd like to use a IDE, so I tried the preinstalled Thonny and Geany. In both the command

```
import pyrealsense2 as rs
```

which in both cases resulted in

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyrealsense2'
```

like in python2 terminal.

Then I tried to manipulate the commands in "Set Build Commands" in Geany as well as the Python executable in Thonny Settings to

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

beacause this is what

```
which python3
```

from my terminal said, but it still does not work.
Any ideas where to look or what to do to get the library running? I would appreciate any further hint

**Edit:**

I've now copied the content (.so-Files) of my library into a subdirectory of my project location (projectDir/librealsense) and imported from there:

```
import librealsense.pyrealsense2 as rs
```

Now it works at least in Thonny. But why are the enviroments always different, and what would be the proper way to tell the IDE to use the same environment as the terminal does?

Comment: what does `import pyrealsense2; print(pyrealsense2.__file__)` give you in terminal?